# Strange colors on image in browser?

Tags: css, safari

When I view an image in Safari at actual size (100% - Command-0) I am getting these strange purple lines appearing. However they look ok in Firefox and Chrome.

Interestingly when I enlarge (Command +) or decrease the view (command -) in the browser, everything looks fine.

Comment: Upload it to IMGUR and add the link to your question

Comment: Can you add a link ti the image in the comments? I will then add to the question